# Swift 3: Iterate through a _NSSingleObjectArrayI

Tags: swift

I'm fetching data from a weather API. I'm not sure how to access the description?

```
"weather": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x608000012910>(
{
    description = "overcast clouds";
    icon = 04n;
    id = 804;
    main = Clouds;
}
)
```

I tried:

```
print(weatherDict["weather"]!.description!)
```

It just gave me this:

```
(
    {
    description = "overcast clouds";
    icon = 04n;
    id = 804;
    main = Clouds;
  }
)
```

How do I properly access the description?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- `weather` contains an array of dictionaries.
- `description` is a key in the first item of the array.

The code unwraps `weather` safely and checks if the array is not empty:

```
if let weatherArray = weatherDict["weather"] as? [[String:Any]], 
   let weather = weatherArray.first {
       print(weather["description"]) // the value is an optional.
}
```